# Animated change in Picker will run animation multiple times

Tags: swiftui

I have the following code:

```
import SwiftUI

let names = ["John", "Betty", "Fred", "May", "Judy"]

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0

    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Picker("Name", selection: self.$selection.animation(.linear(duration: 0.3))) {
                ForEach(names.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text(names[i]).tag(i)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Text(names[self.selection])
                .font(.title)
                .fixedSize()
                .modifier(MyShake(animatableData: CGFloat(self.selection)))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}

struct MyShake: GeometryEffect {
    var animatableData: CGFloat

    func modifier(_ x: CGFloat) -> CGFloat {
        10 * sin(x * .pi * 2)
    }

    func effectValue(size: CGSize) -> ProjectionTransform {
        let transform1 = ProjectionTransform(CGAffineTransform(translationX: 10 + modifier(animatableData), y: 0))
        return transform1
    }
}

struct ContentView_Previews: PreviewProvider {
    static var previews: some View {
        ContentView()
        .previewDevice("iPhone SE")
    }
}
```

If you switch from John to Betty (i.e. select a segment next to the current one), the animation will run once, which is exactly what I want. However, if you switch from John to Fred, the animation will run multiple times because the selection actually doesn't move from 0 to 2, but interpolates each step in between.

How can I limit the animation such that it only runs once?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I see it needs to convert `selection` into just `toggle`. Please find below possible approach for this.

Demo:

[image]

#### Updated: Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5

Just simplified variant, so we don't need proxy binding anymore:

```
Text(names[self.selection])
    .font(.title)
    .fixedSize()
    .modifier(MyShake(animatableData: CGFloat(self.shaking ? 1 : 0)))
    .onChange(of: selection) { _ in shaking.toggle() }
    .animation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.3), value: shaking)
```

[Test module on GitHub](https://github.com/Asperi-Demo/4SwiftUI/blob/master/PlayOn_iOS/PlayOn_iOS/Findings/TestGeometryEffectOnPickerSelection.swift)

#### Original

Tested & works with Xcode 11.2 / iOS 13.2

Changes are only in `ContentView`:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State var selection = 0
    @State var shaking = false
    var body: some View {
        let value = Binding<Int>(
            get: { self.selection },
            set: { newValue in
                withAnimation(Animation.linear(duration: 0.3)) {
                    self.shaking.toggle()
                }
                self.selection = newValue
            })
        return VStack(spacing: 20) {
            Picker("Name", selection: value) {
                ForEach(names.indices, id: \.self) { i in
                    Text(names[i]).tag(i)
                }
            }.pickerStyle(SegmentedPickerStyle())
            Text(names[self.selection])
                .font(.title)
                .fixedSize()
                .modifier(MyShake(animatableData: CGFloat(self.shaking ? 1 : 0)))
        }
        .padding()
    }
}
```

Comment: Interesting solution. The custom binding makes it possible to spread the change to two state variables. Then the animation is driven from the bool state variable, instead of the int state variable. Clever.