# How can make a shake effect in SwiftUI?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I want make a shake effect with offset, looking to have zero offset at beging and shaking in between 30.0 and -30.0, covering this offset: -30.0, 0.0, 30.0

But in coding I cannot have those 3 options, and i have 2 options, my goal is to start with 0.0 going to 30.0 then going to -30.0 and at last ending to 0.0

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var start: Bool = false
    var body: some View {

        Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
            .font(Font.system(size: 50))
            .offset(x: start ? 30.0 : -30.0)
            .padding()
            .animation(Animation.spring(response: 0.2, dampingFraction: 0.2, blendDuration: 0.2), value: start)
        
        Button("Shake") {
            start.toggle()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Does this answer your question https://stackoverflow.com/a/60154727/12299030?

Comment: I think the sin function is most important in that link which is very good approach. I believe in some way I should animate the sin value to be smooth animation.

Comment: Check this, it may hep you https://www.objc.io/blog/2019/10/01/swiftui-shake-animation/

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You can use an explicit animation with the button instead of the implicit one. Then in the button fist shift by offset without animation, and shift back with animation:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @State private var start: Bool = false
    var body: some View {
        
        VStack {
            Image(systemName: "exclamationmark.triangle")
                .font(Font.system(size: 50))
                .offset(x: start ? 30 : 0)
                .padding()
            
            Button("Shake") {
                start = true
                withAnimation(Animation.spring(response: 0.2, dampingFraction: 0.2, blendDuration: 0.2)) {
                    start = false
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image]